# Best Practice for Storing Data from Multiple Sources for Machine Learning Purposes

Tags: mysql, json, mongodb, csv, storage

Currently, I am pulling data from multiple sources and investigating different methods of machine learning to train models using these data sets. Moving forward, I want to come up with the best plan for data storage.

At the moment, I am using plain old CSVs. However, one reason why I am motivated to switch is due to the existence of related fields in the data sets that all belong to the same object. For example, if we are storing data about multiple restaurants I will number the restaurant and have multiple fields for it. More specifically, I will have a fields in the header that are related i.e. `restaurant_1_name`, `restaurant_1_location`, `restaurant_2_name`, `restaurant_2_location`... and so on. Furthermore, in particular cases, some data points will have a variable number of restaurants, so I will have to create null entries for many of the potential fields in the CSV. Moreover, to add to this variability, data from different sources will have additional fields and missing fields.

Due to the object-oriented nature of our data, I thought it might be better to consider another form of data storage. As an initial solution JSON comes to mind as it allows for a variable number of attributes and grouping of objects as lists of dictionaries. As a bonus, it is a fairly compatible form with Python dictionaries and the pandas module, the language/module I am using (but so are most data formats).

**Based on the nature of this data, what are the best practices and methodologies for choosing the most viable data approach among options such as CSV, JSON, NoSQL (i.e. Mongo), SQL (i.e. Postgres, MySQL) keeping in mind the variability among the data sources/points and the objective nature of the data? Furthermore, is it worth consolidating data into one format or rather keeping it separate by data source?**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going with mongo as it is flexible enough and it allows you to store unstructured data and it will be much easier to query. IMO